# Excel Conditional Formatting for Cell condition in Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

How do I reference another cell in my conditional formatting?

I want an entire range to highlight in green if a particular cell in that range is populated with "y".

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1 * IFERROR(FIND("y", $A$1:$D$1), FALSE))
```

Just change your range to suit.  SUMPRODUCT is a non-array formula that treats the range as an array, so it does the FIND on each cell in the range.  If any of them contain a "y", then it ends up with a non-zero value, and the condition happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a formula or rule to always reflect a certain column or row.  Simply put a $ (dollar sign) before the column or row.  To always reflect a specific cell, put a $ before the column and row.  For example, to reference cell F3, use `$F$3`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/319238/excel-conditional-formatting-of-row/319759#319759).

For your specific problem, you can try this:

Go to **Conditional Formating** > **New Rule** > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Enter this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$L1, "y")>0
```

Set your format and click **OK**.

Make sure that the **Applies to** box in the **Conditional Formatting Manager** window is set to the range(s) that you wish to apply the condition to.

For this example, if you set the **Applies to** field to `=$A$1:$L$15`, the rule will loop through each row in rows **1** to **15** within the columns **D** to **L** for the value "y" and if it finds it, it will highlight that row. You'll get something like this:

[image]

If you want it to highlight each column of data, instead, change the formula to:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:L$1, "y")>0
```

[image]

If you want to highlight the entire range, change the formula to:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$L$15, "y")>0
```