# conditional formatting of entire row from a cell's value in that particular row in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have viewed the [answer for a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/319238/Excel-conditional-formatting-of-row). If I have several rules for a particular row, (e.g. if cell A2 is 1 then the row is red, if 2 then row is blue, if 3 then row is green, etc...). Having 40 rows and 5 coloring rules, I will have to create 200 rules that is not efficient in my view.

Can I use one rule for all 40 rows, rather than 5 rules for a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Apply the rule to all 40 rows and use a formula like this for each rule:

```
=$A2=1
```

That should only require five rules.